# Hide MORE INFORMATION tab if it's empty in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Want to hide More Information tab under catalog product view in Magento 2.3 if it's empty.

Not sure where to start, below is screenshot,

[image: more info tab]

I use M2.3 and theme is Porto (if that's necessary to know) I checked under `/var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` but not sure if this is where I need to make changes. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect tab and look for id (button) and tab section div class or id.

```
<script>
require(['jquery'], function ($) {
    "use strict";
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert($("#additional").find('tbody').html().trim().length);
        if ($("#additional").find('tbody').html().trim().length <= 0) {
            $("#tab-label-additional").hide();
        }else{

        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I this will fulfill your need in easy way.

Happy coding

Comment: Thanks Nilesh, I have inspected the tab and found this `<a class="data switch" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="switch" href="#additional" id="tab-label-additional-title">` but I am not sure where should I add the jquery code you posted in your comment?

Comment: you can add this in any .phtml file on the product view page

Comment: sorry but not sure under what path because I have 2 different paths for .phtml files under product view one is `var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view` and another is under `/var/www/html/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view`

Comment: Use this one app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view and if possible look for addtocart.phtml 

and Also, please do not share "var/www/HTML" or whatever - Share the only paths like this ( just saying ) app/code or vendor

Comment: I added the code to addtocart.phtml like this,
`<script>
require(['jquery'], function ($) {
    "use strict";
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($(".data switch").html().length <= 0) {
            $("#tab-label-additional-title").hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>` 
But the page is not loading correctly (cache cleared)  Please let me know if added the code correctly

Comment: Provide me a link or screenshot of the tab button and tab content area

Comment: I have updated the post and Add this also add this in the same file addtocart.phtml

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks!! Accepted your answer too! Only issue is I had to comment the `//alert($("#additional").find('tbody').html().trim().length);` because on page load it is showing an unnecessary alert popup. Everything else is fine. Can I keep the `alert` line commented?

Comment: Yes, that alert should be commented on. good job